# ArrayList json database

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. есть arrayList с большим количеством координат и нужно его как-то записать на хост и  как-то там его хранить. Может для многих вопрос глупый, но как это сделать? думал может через json отправлять(как обычно делаю), но это как-то тупо и неудобно, а потом эти данные сохранять в базе. Но может можно как-то записать это в xml файл на хосте? можно ли вообще записать данные через инет на какой-то удаленный xml файл?

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParams, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpParams, "UTF-8");
            HttpProtocolParams.setHttpElementCharset(httpParams, "UTF-8");
            httpParams.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version", HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(2000));
            httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", HTTP.UTF_8);

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: не совсем понятно чем вам json не угодил и почему вы считаете xml лучше? 
xml изначально избыточен для передачи данных между мобильным приложением и сервером.

Можете получать данные от мобильного приложения в формате json и сохранять его на сервере в любом формате в виде файла или в базу данных.

Comment: сейчас попробую объяснить почему. приведу кусок кода, каким образом я json формирую. там в массиве 500 значений, как мне их загнать в Numeric ParamValue?

Comment: List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
каким образом запихнуть эти 500 значений сюда из ArrayList<LatLng>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

два самых простых варианта чтобы не отказываться от отлаженного кода с ArrayList<NameValuePair>()

```
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i ++ )
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(String.valueOf(i), arrayList.get(i).toString()));
```

да да мсье знает толк в извращениях )))

второй способ создаем обычный JSONArray, заполняем его нужными данными и

```
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 nameValuePairs.add("arrayLatLng", jsonArrayLatLng.toString());
```

Comment: спасибо. сделал вторым способом

Comment: первый это скорее шутка юмора )) хотя рабочая